# Exporting To Excel From SSRS Fails After Adding Parameters

Tags: excel, reporting-services

We have several reports in SSRS that use stored procedures with parameters.  Until recently they worked fine but now fail to export to Excel.
The results come back fine, they just fail to export to Excel.
When you click to save to excel, a new tab opens up as normal, but it sits there for about 40 minutes before it finally returns "The page cannot be displayed". I created a copy of one of our stored procedures that does not use parameters and a modified of one of our reports to call it. The report without parameters exports to Excel fine. We're stumped.
Thanks

Comment: When you remove the parameter are you adding a WHERE clause so the results aren't too big? I have no evidence, but it sounds like it's trying to return too much data and there's something not right with the parameters. Try changing the SP to include `TOP 10` and see if it returns data.

Comment: How many columns does it generate? If you are using reporting services 2008, it generates a *.xls file with all the limitations they have.